# How to compare list of strings and output number of strings that are not matching?

Tags: r, difference-lists

I have a list as:

```
s <- c('peel', 'peer', 'pear', 'tggc', 'gcgt')
```

I would like to compare each string with every other string in the list and I use the following command:

```
z <- Map(utf8ToInt, s)
dmat <- outer(z, z, FUN=Vectorize(function(x, y) sum(bitwXor(x, y) > 0)))
```

However, I would like to output the number of character differences (instead of characters matching) based on position:

For example `"tggc"` when compared with the string `"gcgt"` should be output as `3`.

Comment: And if the two words to be compared have not the same length?

Comment: the strings are all of equal length. Sorry, I will edit the question.

Comment: If all strings are of equal length, what is stopping you from passing `n - (sum(bitwXor(x, y) > 0))` as the function where n is the string length (possibly passed as a default argument)? You can also use negation as in my answer below.

Comment: I'm not seeing the problem with your current solution. Your current output for the `tggc`/`gcgt` comparison is `3`.

Answer (score 3):

Just use a simple negation `!` as per the following:

```r
s <- c('peel', 'peer', 'pear', 'tggc', 'gcgt')
z <- Map(utf8ToInt, s)
dmat <- outer(z, z, FUN = Vectorize(function(x, y) sum(!bitwXor(x, y))))
dmat
```

Or use a straightforward equality comparison given that you've mapped the characters to integers.

```r
dmat <- outer(z, z, FUN = Vectorize(function(x, y) sum(x == y)))
```

Both give output:

```r
     peel peer pear tggc gcgt
peel    4    3    2    0    0
peer    3    4    3    0    0
pear    2    3    4    0    0
tggc    0    0    0    4    1
gcgt    0    0    0    1    4
```

Note: If you have fixed string length, you can also use subtraction, but the above saves you from passing this explicitly, which adds a little generality.

Comment: Why not simply `sum(x == y)`?

Comment: @jblood94 my initial thoughts were that the bitwise operators were more performant in R, but this appears not to be the case looking into the implementation. I'll add your solution as well. Thank you

Comment: Yep. With a larger vector, `sum(x == y)` clearly performs better. E.g. `s <- mapply(FUN = function(x) paste0(sample(letters[1:4]), collapse = ""), 1:100)`

Answer (score 1):

If performance is a concern:

```
s <- c('peel', 'peer', 'pear', 'tggc', 'gcgt')
z <- mapply(utf8ToInt, s)
n <- length(s)
n1 <- 1:(n - 1L)
replace(matrix(nrow = n, ncol = n),
        sequence(n1, seq(n + 1L, by = n, length.out = n - 1L)),
        colSums(z[, sequence(n1)] == z[, rep.int(2:n, n1)]))
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#> [1,]   NA    3    2    0    0
#> [2,]   NA   NA    3    0    0
#> [3,]   NA   NA   NA    0    0
#> [4,]   NA   NA   NA   NA    1
#> [5,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA

# benchmarking with a larger character vector
s <- mapply(FUN = function(x) paste0(sample(letters[1:4]), collapse = ""), 1:100)
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(bitwXor = {z <- Map(utf8ToInt, s)
                                          outer(z, z, FUN = Vectorize(function(x, y) sum(!bitwXor(x, y))))},
                               logical = {z <- Map(utf8ToInt, s)
                                          outer(z, z, FUN = Vectorize(function(x, y) sum(x == y)))},
                               mat = {z <- mapply(utf8ToInt, s)
                                      n <- length(s)
                                      n1 <- 1:(n - 1L)
                                      replace(matrix(nrow = n, ncol = n),
                                              sequence(n1, seq(n + 1L, by = n, length.out = n - 1L)),
                                              colSums(z[, sequence(n1)] == z[, rep.int(2:n, n1)]))})
#> Unit: microseconds
#>     expr     min      lq      mean   median       uq     max neval
#>  bitwXor 23846.1 24875.6 26207.230 26120.95 27134.35 33842.8   100
#>  logical 16645.5 17514.8 19020.051 18383.35 19875.15 32716.8   100
#>      mat   387.4   455.0   511.322   482.70   544.05  1224.4   100

# confirm that the results are the same
z <- Map(utf8ToInt, s)
mat1 <- outer(z, z, FUN = Vectorize(function(x, y) sum(!bitwXor(x, y))))
mat2 <- outer(z, z, FUN = Vectorize(function(x, y) sum(x == y)))
z <- mapply(utf8ToInt, s)
n <- length(s)
n1 <- 1:(n - 1L)
mat3 <- replace(matrix(nrow = n, ncol = n), sequence(n1, seq(n + 1L, by = n, length.out = n - 1L)), colSums(z[, sequence(n1)] == z[, rep.int(2:n, n1)]))
all.equal(mat1[upper.tri(mat1)], mat2[upper.tri(mat2)])
#> [1] TRUE
all.equal(mat1[upper.tri(mat1)], mat3[upper.tri(mat3)])
#> [1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution:

```r
library(tidyverse)

sample <- c('peel','peer','pear','tggc','gcgt')

sample %>% 
  expand.grid(sample) %>% 
  rowwise %>% 
  mutate(cmp = mapply(function(x,y) 
                { x != y}, x=str_split(Var1, ""), y=str_split(Var2, "")) %>% sum)

#> # A tibble: 25 × 3
#> # Rowwise: 
#>    Var1  Var2    cmp
#>    <fct> <fct> <int>
#>  1 peel  peel      0
#>  2 peer  peel      1
#>  3 pear  peel      2
#>  4 tggc  peel      4
#>  5 gcgt  peel      4
#>  6 peel  peer      1
#>  7 peer  peer      0
#>  8 pear  peer      1
#>  9 tggc  peer      4
#> 10 gcgt  peer      4
#> # … with 15 more rows
```